# Report number of assertions in pyTest

Tags: python, integration-testing, pytest

I am using `pytest` for writing some tests at integration level. I would like to be able to also report the number of assertions done on each test case. By default, `pytest` will only report the number of test cases which have passed and failed.

Comment: You will have to better define what counts as an assertion.  You can't just count the assert statements, because for example something like `with pytest.raises:` is still a type of test assertion.

Comment: I want to count all assert_that calls done during a test case and add it to the JUnit test report for example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On assertion further execution of test is aborted. So there will always be 1 assertion per test.

To achieve what you want you will have to write your own wrapper over assertion to keep track. At the end of the test check if count is >0 then raise assertion.
The count can be reset to zero either the `setup` or at `teardown` of test.

Comment: A test is not generally aborted after an assertion, it is only aborted if the assertion **fails**, i.e. the condition is not met.

What nnja wants is just to count how many assertions have **passed**. Many test frameworks report that number by default.

IMHO it is - amongst others - a valid measure for test quality; "sloppy" tests might apply too few checks to values

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see there is no such possibility to get the number of passed assertions out of pytest.

Reason: it employs Python's standard `assert` statement, so the determination whether the assertion is a pass or a fail is done within the engine used, and in case the engine does not count how often it got into the "pass" branch of the necessary `if` in `assert`'s implementation, and offer a way to read out that counter, there is just **no way** to elicit that information from the engine. So pyTest can't tell you that either.

Many (unit) test frameworks report assertion count by default, and IMHO i deem it desirable, because it is - amongst others - a measure for test quality: sloppy tests might apply too few checks to values.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a reasonable solution to the problem -- just count the occurrences of the string `assert` in all test files.

Check out the code comments at the top of the script for more details.

Full Gist here: https://gist.github.com/thehunmonkgroup/c24fc8aaf064cd81a79e987fded055d4

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# pytest provides no mechanism for counting the number of assertions in tests.
#
# This seems like useful information, and this script provides a *reasonable*
# method to get a count.
#
# Since it's simply counting occurances of the string 'assert', it's not
# guaranteed to be fully accurate, but given that a true assert statement
# usually only has one 'assert' string per line, and given that in a test
# file, it would be unusual to have the string 'assert' that is not actually
# an assertion, this approach should still give pretty solid data.
#
# USAGE:
# 
# 1. Drop it in the main pytest 'tests' directory
# 2. Make it executable
# 3. Run without arguments to get total assertion count
# 4. Run with the '-h' argument for help

import os

DEFAULT_TEST_DIRECTORY = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))


def count_asserts_in_file(file_path, debug):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        count = file.read().count('assert')
    if debug:
        print(f"{file_path}: {count} asserts")
    return count


def count_asserts_in_directory(directory_path, debug):
    total_asserts = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.startswith('test_') and file.endswith('.py'):
                total_asserts += count_asserts_in_file(os.path.join(root, file), debug)
    return total_asserts


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Count the number of 'assert' statements in test files.")
    parser.add_argument('directory', metavar='DIR', type=str, nargs='?', default=DEFAULT_TEST_DIRECTORY,
                        help='the directory to analyze (default: %(default)s)')
    parser.add_argument('--debug', action='store_true', help='Print the number of asserts for each file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    directory_path = args.directory
    debug = args.debug
    total_asserts = count_asserts_in_directory(directory_path, debug)
    print(f"Total asserts in {directory_path}: {total_asserts}")
```