# Using pytest, how can I assert that an assertion actually happened?

Tags: pytest

I'd like to be able to make "meta" assertions, a la tools like Jest, with pytest.

For instance, say I have a list of items I'm iterating over and during this iteration I'm making assertions--this works as expected as long as the list is not empty. However if the list is empty, the code doesn't execute but my test happily passes (i.e. not assertions failed). Of course one could check that the length of the list (assuming we're dealing with a list and not a different iterable like a generator), but that might not fit my use case.

So how can I ensure that assertions actually happen in my tests using pytest?

Comment: You already mentioned making assertion on length of the iterable but it doesn't work well with generators. Other similar solutions would be to use a mutable counter incremented in each iteration or `enumerate` builtin function and asserting the counter's/index's value outside the loop.

Comment: I think you have to roll your own here, if you can't assert that your iterable is empty (which is the usual way to do this). See also [this issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/643) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39500416/report-number-of-assertions-in-pytest).